# Mongodb findAndModify on an array

Tags: mongodb

I have an array of objects:

```
[{
  _id: 1,
  data: 'one'
},{
  _id: 2,
  data: 'two'
}]
```

I am receiving a new array every so often.  Is there a way to shove all the data back into mongo (without dups) in bulk.

I.E. I know that I can loop over each element and and do a findAndModify (with upsert true for new records coming in).  But I cann do an insert with the array each time because the ids will collide.

Comment: Are you importing the data (mongoimport) or data is processed in some code you have?

Comment: If you just want to insert new documents and don't want to update the documents with duplicate _id, you can use bulk inserts with ContinueOnError option. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-inserts/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the shell if you try to insert the whole array in one step it cycles through each element of the array and works, so the instruction:

```
db.coll.insert([{   _id: 1,   data: 'one' },{   _id: 2,   data: 'two' }])
```

Works and inserts two different records.
_id check also works, if you try it again you will receive an error as expected.
Anyway, there's a downside and it's the fact Mongo cycles every single record for real, and in  case you try something like:

```
db.col.insert([{   _id: 1,   data: 'one again' },{   _id: 5,   data: 'five' }])
```

It won't work to test duplicates due to the fact Mongo stops in the first record and the second is never processed.
There're a couple of other tricks to insert this into a collection with a single node named "data" for example and process it faster, however you're always limited to 16mb records, if your bulk data is too large no any method will work.

In case you use mongoimport it's possible to use the --jsonArray parameter but you're still limited to 16 mb.

There's not another way to do it if you need larger chunks of data.